# Problems with the W3C validator

Tags: html, css

My website code is working fine but when i put in the w3c validator it shows me some errors and when i fix them my website gets all messed up. Basically my code is working with the "errors" that the validator points me. I don't know what to do since this code is a test for my college and probably my professor will put the code at the validator too.

I'm a beginner at programming so i did the html and the css separately (there is no js because i don't know how to use it and my professor didn't teach us yet)

```css
* {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
#container{
  width: 1348px;
  height: 312px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.logo {
  width: 208px;
  height: 208px;
  background: url("../IMG/logo.png");
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 87px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.caixa_texto_quemsomos {
  width: 172px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 156px;
  left: 512px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.quemsomos {
  width: 172px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.caixa_texto_contato {
  width: 172px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 156px;
  left: 757px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.contato {
  width: 172px;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.barralaranja1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background: #FB9324;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section_foto {
  width: 450px;
  height: 505px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 378px;
  left: 415px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.foto {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  background: url("../IMG/foto.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.maisdetalhes {
  width: 174px;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 479px;
  left: 138px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.div_rodape {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 939px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.rodape {
  width: 100%;
  height: 78px;
  background: #5DBCD2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.direitosreservados {
  width: 338px;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 174px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ajuda {
  width: 81px;
  color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 798px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.barralaranja2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  background: #FB9324;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.instagram {
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  background: url("../IMG/instagram.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 1096px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Index.css">
<head>
    <title>Gente - Arquitetura Colaborativa</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id=container>
    <header>
        <figure class="logo">
            <img src="IMG/logo.png" alt="logo_img">
        </figure>

        <nav class="caixa_texto_quemsomos">
            <a class="quemsomos" href="Quem_Somos.html" target="_blank">QUEM SOMOS</a>
        </nav>

        <nav class="caixa_texto_contato">
            <a class="contato" href="Contato.html" target="_blank">CONTATO</a>
        </nav>

    </header>
    </div>

    <div class="barralaranja1"></div>

    <main>
        <section class="section_foto">

        <figure class="foto">
            <img src="IMG/foto.jpeg" alt="foto_img">
        </figure>

        <a class="maisdetalhes" href="Redirecionamento_Imagem.html" target="_blank">Mais detalhes...</a>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="div_rodape">
            <div class="rodape">
        </div>

        <div class="barralaranja2"></div>

        <p class="direitosreservados">Todos os direitos reservados ©</p>

        <a class="ajuda" href="Index.html" target="_blank">Ajuda</a>

        <a class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/gentearq/" target="_blank">
            <img src="IMG/instagram.png" alt="instagram_img">
        </a>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

The errors are:

1. Error: Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open. From line 5, column 1; to line 5, column 6 dex.css">↩↩ <tit
2. Warning: Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections. From line 31, column 3; to line 31, column 32 ↩ ↩↩ <f
3. Error: End tag footer seen, but there were open elements. From line 55, column 2; to line 55, column 10 >↩ ↩ ↩↩</bo
4. Error: Unclosed element div. From line 42, column 3; to line 42, column 26 footer>↩ ↩ <d

Comment: Pls post those codes so that we can see what are you doing

Comment: And the errors too.

Comment: Your answer is attracting downvotes because it isn't very specific.  In the future, I'd recommend posting your question with a single specific error and code, with details as to what happens when you try to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time using stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed list for getting a valid HTML document

#### 1. Error: Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open.

Because you have put some tags that belongs to the head element outside of it so this

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Index.css">
<head>
  <title>Gente - Arquitetura Colaborativa</title>
</head>
```

needs to be this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Index.css">
  <title>Gente - Arquitetura Colaborativa</title>
</head>
```

#### 2. Warning: Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections.

So this is just a warning, because each section needs at least one heading element for example, and you
can see that it gives an advice to use from h2 to h6 heading tags.

```
<section class="section_foto">
  <h3>Foto</h3>
  <figure class="foto">
    <img src="IMG/foto.jpeg" alt="foto_img">
  </figure>
  <a class="maisdetalhes" href="Redirecionamento_Imagem.html" target="_blank">Mais detalhes...</a>
</section>
```

#### 3. Error: End tag footer seen, but there were open elements.

This error means you have a non void html element that needs to be closed before the closing footer tag, and that means it's a child
of this footer element so this

```
<footer>
  <div class="div_rodape">
    <div class="rodape">
  </div>
```

needs to be this

```
<footer>
  <div class="div_rodape">
    <div class="rodape"></div>
  </div>
```

#### 4. Error: Unclosed element div.

This error have already been corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, since this is for a test, you should find a way to implement the fixes for "Error"s, but not necessarily "Warning"s.

W3C is checking if you have written valid html.  Invalid html often works, so I'm not surprised that your code works.  If this was a web development job I would say "If it works, it's great" but since it's a test of your knowledge of code I think you'd better do it the "proper" way.

For example, this very Stack Overflow page has many errors such as:

Error: Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context.

This page would get a "pass" from a client, but maybe not from a professor.

Answer (score 0):

Let's address each of these concerns individually:

> Basically my code is working with the "errors" that the validator points me.

Browsers are very forgiving, and do their best to fix the page.  A page can be quite broken and will still display correctly.  However, an invalid page may be more likely to display incorrectly across different browsers.  It may also parse badly for crawlers, making it harder for your page to show up in search results.  Alternative browsers, such as text mode browsers, may have other issues.

You should fix these errors.  Fortunately, they're pretty straightforward once you know what the validator is really getting at.

> Error: Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open.

You only have one `<head>` tag, however the validator says your `<head>` tag was already open.  The reason is that your `<head>` tag was *implicitly* opened because you used `<meta>` and `<link>` tags before it.  These belong inside `<head>`.  The parser had to implicitly create a `<head>` element to attach them to, so by the time it gets to your actual `<head>` tag, there is now a duplicate, which is not allowed.

You can fix this by simply moving your `<meta>` and `<link>` tags inside your `<head></head>`.

> Warning: Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements to add identifying headings to all sections.

Most sections are going to have some heading as a title to the text or other content that follows within that section.  If yours doesn't, it may not be necessary.

> Error: End tag footer seen, but there were open elements.

> Error: Unclosed element div.

What this means is that you opened a tag but didn't close it.  The validator has gotten close to where the problem is:

```
    <div class="div_rodape">
        <div class="rodape">
    </div>
```

Just add a `</div>` after `<div class="rodape">`.  Otherwise, the browser assumes that it's the *outer* element (`.div_rodape`) that isn't closed.  This is because the browser doesn't care about your indentation.

It's good to see that they're using a validator in class!  Always a good tool to have.